# C++ binary compatible dll POD class member initialization causes crash

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mingw, binary-compatibility

I'm trying to make an inter-compiler compatible class in a dll built with mingw that can be used in a Windows VS application. My issue is, my class crashes the moment it tries to initialize a member variable when a function is called from the VS program. Using the STL or making local variables within the same functions works fine.

Unhandled exception at 0x6BEC19FE (test.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x154EB01E.

Simple demonstration:

The dll code

```
#include <iostream>

class Tester 
{
public:

    virtual void test() = 0;
};

class TesterImp : public Tester
{
public:
    TesterImp(){}
    ~TesterImp(){}

    virtual void test() { 
        int test = 5; // fine
        m_test = 5; // access violation
    }

private:

    int m_test;

};

    extern "C"
    {
        __declspec (dllexport) Tester* Create()
        {
            return new TesterImp();
        }
    }
```

Main program that loads the dll and calls the test function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h> 

class Tester 
{
public:

    virtual void test() = 0;
};

typedef Tester* (*createPtr)();

int main(int argc, const char **argv, char * const *envp) {

  HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibraryA("test.dll");

  if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
    std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  createPtr ctr = (createPtr)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "Create");
  if (!ctr) {
    std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::cout << "dll loading success!" << std::endl;

  Tester* testf = ctr();

  std::cout << "Got test class" << std::endl;

  testf->test(); // crash if the member variable is referenced, fine otherwise with local variable initialization or STL use inside the function

  std::cout << "Running dll functions success!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Main program is compiled in debug mode with VS2012 and the dll is built using g++ from mingw -

> g++ -shared -o test.dll test.cpp

Could someone explain this behavior for me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd start by ensuring your calling conventions matched up, followed by stepping into `ctr()` with a debugger, which will tell you almost immediately what the issue is. I'm also not entirely clear on where your claim of accessing a dynamic allocated derived class with virtual methods through an abstract base interface qualifies as a POD-*anything* in C++.

Comment: `Tester` is not a POD.

Comment: I was referring to int m_test as the POD class member.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't debug that function through VS since mingw doesn't generate the symbols file VS uses for debugging.

Comment: Well I've tried messing with the calling conventions to no avail, looks like I might need to just write the whole interface as exported C style functions.

Comment: @user2380227: you might not get symbols, but VS will step through the MinGW DLL function in the disassembly window.  The `TesterImp::test()` function is only about 10 lines of assembly so it probably shouldn't be too painful too follow.

Comment: @user2380227: what versions of MSVC and MinGW are you using - this seems to work for me with MSVC 2010 and MinGW 4.7.2

Comment: VS 2012 and latest mingw, I'll try it with VS 2010 and see what happens. You compiled this code without any changes?

Comment: Yes - I compiled without changes.  Are you sure that you used the latest MinGW?  I was about to post an answer that speculated that you're using a version of MinGW with GCC 4.6.x or eariler. Before 4.7.0, MinGW passed the `this` pointer on the stack - MSVC expects it in `ecx` (which MinGW 4.7.0 and later do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an older version of MinGW. Up until 4.7.0 (I think), MinGW passed the `this` pointer on the stack which is different than MSVC's `thiscall` convention of passing the `this` pointer in `ecx`.

Starting with 4.7.0, MinGW uses the same `thiscall` calling convention as MSVC.

I can also get the example `TesterImp::test()` function to be called from MSVC successfully by marking both `Tester::test()` and `TesterImp::test()` in `test.cpp` with the `__attribute__((thiscall))` attribute.  This worked with MinGW 4.6.2, which would cause a crash without the attribute being used.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just checked the gcc version and it was 4.62 (not sure how that happened, I got the latest package installer from the mingw site). Thank you very much for your time, you've really helped me out!